# Plotting a graph with the y-axis in order

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I tried to plot a graph using matplotlib and pandas. The result was a graph but the y axis was not in order. I am attaching some screenshots and code. Here is the graph and the code. [image]

Here is the dataframe:[image]

As you can see the y axis of the graph is not in order. So any solution to this problem?

Comment: your data are strings. convert them to numbers before plotting

Comment: And how do we do that?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following to convert your data to `float` type before plotting

```
plt.plot(list(map(float, nedata['2004-05'])))
plt.plot(list(map(float, nedata['2011-12'])))
```

Alternately, you can convert your both columns to float and then plot as your were doing

```
nedata['2004-05'] = nedata['2004-05'].astype('float64')
nedata['2011-12'] = nedata['2011-12'].astype('float64')

plt.plot(nedata['2004-05'])
plt.plot(nedata['2011-12'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow @Diziet Asahi's comment, you can convert the type by this

```py
for var in nedata.columns:
    nedata[var] = nedata[var].astype(float)
```

I think this way is more concise.